Powershell script to find freespace available on disk and send email
$disksize = $null

$limitGB = $null

$freeSpaceGB = $null

#Parameter
$limitGB = 150

$disksize = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName servername-SharepointDB -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-object Name -eq "F:"

$freeSpaceGB = [math]::round($disksize.FreeSpace/1GB, 2)

If ($freeSpaceGB -lt $limitGB) {


Copy
$options = @{

'SmtpServer' = "server.smtp.com" 

'To' = "Recipient"

'From' = "sender" 

'Subject' = "F: Drive space threshold reached - $freeSpaceGB GB Free" 

'Body' = "The F: drive is below 150 GB and only at $freeSpaceGB GB - Please resolve" 

 }

Here is the code and I am getting email

The F: drive is below 150 GB and only at 0 GB - Please resolve

but that is not true. F drive is not low in space

Problem with calculating DiskSize ? If DiskSize is null then freeSpaceGB is null and then your condition is true... and the email is sent

To expand on the other comment, $null will coerce to 0 when used in math, so 0 / 1GB == 0

How should I correct this code? What should be the right syntax
